# Download file with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file, download

Im trying to create some sort of cloud for my RaspberryPi. Where user can login, upload and download files, for which they have permission to access.

To provide this securty, the files get stored in the dir "/var/www/files/", so at a place the browser can not directly access them.

Over PHP a download should be initiated (after checking the users privilages).

The logic to upload files, and display the stored files i already have implemented, but i struggle to find a solution on how to download files.

The upload is working with an ajax call, not sure tho if a download also is possible with that method.

Comment: Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemFileEntry

Comment: Ajax just means "making an HTTP request triggered by JavaScript". It is still an HTTP request made by the browser. So "the files should not be stored in a path the browser can access" won't help because to make them available to Ajax you have to make them available to the browser.

Comment: You don't need to use AJAX to download a file.

Comment: @Mohsen It looks like the link you provided is about creating files on the Windows System the client is running on. I´m looking for a way to load files from a server.

Comment: @Quentin The HTTP-Request should point on a PHP-File on the Server (in path accasable in browser), which should provide the file. And thats the question how to do this. (Not sure tho if I´m confusing something here)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sinc i explained the file is not in a Dir accessable by the browser. the ajax should point to a PHP-File which should provide the File.

Comment: @FatTony — Then you've got two different problems. (1) Making an Ajax request that gets turned into a download. (2) Generating a download response from PHP. The second can be useful for adding a layer of authn/authz. The first seems entirely pointless. As it stands though, your question is too broad and you should focus on one of the problems.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry for the obvioulsy unclear question. The second seems like the solution I´m looking for. The browser should not be able to access the file, since only a logged in (authorised) user should be able to see/download files.

Comment: @Quentin I edited my question, hope its more clear now what I´m trying to achive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP to download a file outside the website root directory. This is quite simple:

```
<?php

$path = <path to the file to be downloaded>;

readfile($path);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Make sure you have access to the file and put this PHP code in a file that is accessible by the browser. With a few headers you can make it nicer:

```
<?php

$path = <path to the file to be downloaded>;
$name = 'Your download name';    
$size = filesize($path);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.$size);

readfile($path);
```

but in the end it is exactly the same. If you want to do some authentication you can do this in PHP.

Comment: Just was I was looking for thanks. I also found this solution myself just now :). Also worth mentioning is that in js the PHP needs to be called by `window.location = [php-path]` instead of an http-request.

Comment: The link I just found (Demo at page bottom): https://www.codexworld.com/force-download-file-php/

Comment: Yes, it wasn't too difficult. Oh, the `window.location = [php-path]` is one way to make an 'http-request'. Another way would be to click on a link or button: meaning the `<a>` and `<input>` html tags.